# How can I specify paths in Fuseki?

Tags: sparql, jena, semantic-web, fuseki

I have a Fuseki server running (`fuseki-server --mem /ds`) with a dataset at path /ds. So far I can upload new models to that dataset and execute queries on it. When I browse to `http://localhost:3030/ds/`, it has all the triple from the model (as expected):

```
<http://localhost:3030/ds/person/5>
        a          foaf:Person ;
        foaf:name  "Borys" .

<http://localhost:3030/ds/person/6>
        a          foaf:Person ;
        foaf:name  "Andy" .
```

My question is: is it possible to upload portions of this model to customized paths in the Fuseki server? For example, a way of browsing to `<http://localhost:3030/ds/person/5>` and obtaining only the following triples.

```
<http://localhost:3030/ds/person/5>
            a          foaf:Person ;
            foaf:name  "Borys" .
```

I may be a bit confused but it would be interesting to query individual instances like:

```
SELECT ?p ?o
WHERE { <http://localhost:3030/ds/person/5> ?p ?o }
```

And so far the closest I got to this solution was to create named graphs for each person.

Comment: Some random pointers: Fuseki supports the [Graph Store Protocol](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-http-rdf-update/), so if you've split your data into named graphs, then each graph can be accessed over HTTP under a (non-pretty) URL. SPARQL also supports [`DESCRIBE` queries](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#describe) that only return the triples for a specific resource. Then there are tools like [Pubby](http://wifo5-03.informatik.uni-mannheim.de/pubby/) (there are probably more modern alternatives) that you can put in front of a SPARQL endpoint to get “pretty” HTTP-resolvable resource URLs.

Comment: That would mean a dataset per path? Doesn't sound like a good solution to me. On the other hand, it looks like you want some kind of Linked Data interface similar to [pubby](https://github.com/cygri/pubby) j

Comment: @cygri I guess I mixed storage and interface support... Thank you for the Pubby suggestion, I think it's what I need.

Comment: One way is to have named graphs and a union graph for the dataset. Fuseki does support GSP direct naming but direct naming is fragile.  http://MyRealHost:3030/ds/person/5 is different to when "localhost" is used. This sounds more like a Link Data Patform use case - [Trellis-LDP](https://github.com/trellis-ldp/trellis) is one such system.